# how can i convert PT7M37S iso 8601 format to duration in seconds using regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in the dataframe that has PT7M37S type values and i want to convert them all into seconds in duration.I'm thinking of matching strings using regular expression and then parsing the integers.

This is my code so far:`match = re.match('PT(\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d+S)?', duration).groups()`

```
hours = _js_parseInt(match[0]) if match[0] else 0
minutes = _js_parseInt(match[1]) if match[1] else 0
seconds = _js_parseInt(match[2]) if match[2] else 0
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: If it works, probably you should post the question at [codereview.se].

Comment: Is there a particular reason for re-inventing the wheel? There are libraries readily available that do a better job of this.

Comment: Sadly, Libraries are not working for me

Comment: @AbhinavDixit Then either you're doing it wrong, or you've misrepresented the data in your question. PT7M37S will be parsed without any problem with at least the isodate library.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some feedback:

- If you change `(\d+H)?` into `(?:(\d+)H)?`, the `\d+H` is optional, but only the `\d+` is captured. This makes it easier to convert into a Python integer afterwards.
- You can convert some `n` into integer that is either a string or `None` using `int(n or 0)`. I'm not sure why you would wish to use `_js_parseInt` in Python when you know they're just integers.
- You can treat all the values of `re.match(...).groups()` at once:

  ```
  match = re.match(r'PT(?:(\d+)H)?(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+)S)?', 'PT7M37S')
  (hours, minutes, seconds) = [ int(n or 0) for n in match.groups() ]
  ```
- Be careful of doing `re.match(...).groups()`; if the match fails, `re.match(...)` is `None` and calling `.groups()` on it will result in an `AttributeError` exception. You should consider this corner case.